# Regex for Google Calendar API date output

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have a string containing a date which has a lot of format possibilities.  My regular expression to match it is getting ridiculous and long. I'm hoping to learn a more concise expression. Here are the various formats. I'd like to get each date as its own match:

```
Sat Jul 16, 2011
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6pm to 8pm
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6pm to 8:30pm
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6:30pm to 8pm
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6:30pm to 8:30pm

Sat Jul 16, 2011 to Sun Jul 17, 2011
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6pm to Sun Jul 17, 2011 8pm
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6:30pm to Sun Jul 17, 2011 8pm
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6pm to Sun Jul 17, 2011 8:30pm
Sat Jul 16, 2011 6:30pm to Sun Jul 17, 2011 8:30pm
```

Before I came here to ask, I'd gotten to this point:

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-4]{4} [0-9]{1,2}[ap]{1}m)( to ([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-4]{4} [0-9]{1,2}[ap]{1}m))?
```

Which would return the first date, and the second if it exists, but only for this format: `Sat Jul 16, 2011 6pm to Sun Jul 17, 2011 8pm`. That got absurd.

Edit:

[Someone suggested](http://twitter.com/#!/jamesnw/status/93163021286903808) I check for the "to" portion of the date, and run the regex on each side, rather than trying to account for all cases at once. Still looking for a more concise solution to each side of it, but that will help a lot.

Comment: Well I'd get rid of all the `{1}`s first of all, but that's about it. Actually if you wanted to validate the dates, your regex would be a lot longer. Regexing for validation is never going to be pretty. For that suggestion, the easiest way would be to write an if statement regex matching for `m to [A-Z]` and `m$`, if that exists use a 2 date matcher, if you can't match that use a 1 side matcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the date into two halves as suggested, and then use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to parse both halves. Then it's Date.parse('Sat Jul 16, 2011 6:30pm')

Comment: For your ranges like "Sat Jul 16, 2011 6:30pm to 8:30pm" you would parse the first half, split the second part on the colon, and then use Date.setHours() and Date.setMinutes() on the original value to get the second Date object